# Implied Double Space in Table of Contents Vs. Sections

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I'm attempting to remove a double space that seems to be automatically put after the display of list of figures, table of contents, etc. What I mean visually is show as follows:
[image: Double space after List of Figures]

What I would like however, is something like this (without the double space)

[image: Single space after section]

In my document, displaying the list of figures/table of contents/etc. is automatically generated by the commands `\listoffigures` or `\tableofcontents` respectively. Is there anyway to remove this excess white space?

Comment: Without knowing something more about your document, no one will be likely to be able to help you.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It just needs to have the document class you are using and the relevant contents list lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use [the `tocloft` pacakge](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/), you can adjust the vertical spacing after the title and the fonts of the titles as detailed below.

### Changing Spacing After Title:

The vertical spacing after the titles can be adjusted via the following lengths:

- `\cftafterloftitleskip`: list of figures
- `\cftafterlottitleskip`: list of tables
- `\cftaftertoctitleskip`: table of contents

Here is a comparison of the default setting for `cftafterloftitleskip` compared to the setting it to `12pt`:

[image]
[image]

---

### Changing Font:

Assuming you are *not* using the `[titles]` option when loading the `tocloft` package you can change the font of the titles with `\renewcommand` to adjust:

- `\cftloftitlefont`: list of figures
- `\cftlottitlefont`: list of tables
- `\cfttoctitlefont`: table of contents

Here is a comparison of the font adjusted for the LOF, vs the default for LOT using:

```
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{12pt}

%\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}% To change font of the LOF title

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{figure}
    \caption{First Figure in Chapter One}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \caption{First Figure in Chapter One}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Second Figure in Chapter One}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Second Figure in Chapter One}
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{figure}
    \caption{First Figure in Chapter Two}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \caption{First Figure in Chapter Two}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter, is there anyway to reduce the font size of the List of Figures while taking advantage of this package? Thanks.

Comment: @VincentRusso: Have updated the answer to show how to change the font of the titles from `tocloft` package.

Comment: Thanks again for the very prompt response Peter. Very helpful indeed, thank you very much.

Comment: @VincentRusso: You're welcome. But, in the future, please get in the habit of composing a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), even if it seems trivial, that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will save a everyone a lot of time and you'll get your questions answered more quickly.  I see that you have not done that in the past for your questions.